# Acf repeater in loop

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, repeater, advanced-custom-fields

I have problem in this loop.
I tried to use Acf repeater images but it doesn't create rows and doesn't show images.
I add the code below, it works very well.
I want to add down the main image one carousuel.
But most of all I want try to have repeater images

```
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'progetto',
        'posts_per_page' => -1
    );

    // Query the posts:
    $grid_post_types_query = new WP_Query($args);
    if ($grid_post_types_query->have_posts()) {
              $grid_img = '';
              $grid_details = '';
              $i = 1;
              while ($grid_post_types_query->have_posts()) : $grid_post_types_query->the_post();
                $image_id = get_post_thumbnail_id();
                $image_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src($image_id,'progetti');
                $url = $image_url[0];
                $image_id = get_post_thumbnail_id();
                $image_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src($image_id,'full');
                $url2 = $image_url[0];
                $content = wpautop(get_the_content());




$grid_img .= ' <li class="gridder-list" data-griddercontent="#gridder-content-' . $i . '"> <img src="' . $url . '" class="img-responsive" /></li>';
$grid_details .= '<div id="gridder-content-' . $i . '" class="gridder-content">
<div class="row">

    <div class="col-sm-6">  <img src=" ' . $url2 . '" class="img-responsive" />  


    here i would like have repeater image </div> 


    <div class="col-sm-6"> ' . $content . ' </div>  

 </div> 

</div>';

  $i++;
              endwhile;
           echo  $output = '<div class="container griddercontainer"><ul class="gridder"> ' . $grid_img . '</ul>' . $grid_details . '  </div>';
    }
    wp_reset_postdata();
    wp_reset_query();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the typical loop to fit your code

```
<?php $nbr = 1; ?>

<div class="row">
  <div class="container">
    <?php query_posts('post_type=progetto'); while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

      <?php $image = get_field('IMAGE_ACF_FIELD'); ?>

      <div id="image-<?php echo $nbr; ?>" class="col-sm-6"><img src="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image['alt']; ?>" /></div>

    <?php $nbr++; endwhile; wp_reset_query(); ?>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please provide an explaination whenever you post any code, as a general habit. It will help the asker in understanding how it works.

Comment: hi, yes i need for ad after owl carosuel for slide picture of single project. Like google images, but i want add slide for every single project down main picture.

I not understand how add in my loop the code of acf